# SVG Images not linked properly inside Master SVG

Tags: python, xslt, svg

Through a python program, i am generating some SVG images. Each of this SVG Image has an external PNG Image attached to it.

Individually all these SVG images are good and look perfect.

But then i am creating a master SVG, which contains all these previously created SVG images (linked via image tag). When i view the master SVG in inkscape (on ubuntu), the PNG images are not displaying.

Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

NOTE: All Images (SVG and PNG) are linked by absolute paths on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an SVG image via the `<image>` tag then it must be [complete in a single file](http://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/) i.e. it can't link to an external png file.

You could convert the png file to a data URL and embed it in the SVG image file.

Comment: I will try that. Right now i am trying to nest SVG elements instead of image linking. I am hoping that will work.